# What is the radius of convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^{n^{3}}}{n^4}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

What is the radius of convergence of the series  $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^{n^{3}}}{n^4}?$$

This question is #1 from [here](https://math.illinois.edu/system/files/inline-files/comp542_aug12.pdf).

The sum converges when $z=1$. When $|z|>1$ we have $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{z^{n^{3}}}{n^4} \neq 0.$$
Is this enough to conclude that the radius of convergence is 1?

Comment: Yes, it is${}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{z^{n^3}}{n^4} = \sum^\infty_{k=1}a_kz^k
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
a_k =
\begin{cases}
n^{-4} & \text{ if }\ \  k=n^3\\
0 & \text{otherwise}. 
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Then it follows
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{R} = \limsup_{k\rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[k]{|a_k|} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt[n^3]{n^4}} = 1.
\end{align}